# getting the current index of a python list

Tags: python, mysql, list

I currently have the following:

```
jsonfiletext = jsonfile.read()
data = json.loads(jsonfiletext)
cursor.execute("SELECT CheckinID FROM checkins ORDER BY CheckinID DESC LIMIT 1")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    checkin_id = row[0]
for checkin in data:
    ~do stuff~
```

data looks like the following:

```
[{u'abc': u'123', u'def': u'456'}, {u'abc': u'789', u'def': u'012'}]
```

however, I was looking to get some form of an index or a key on the dict.

```
jsonfiletext = jsonfile.read()
data = json.loads(jsonfiletext)
cursor.execute("SELECT CheckinID FROM checkins ORDER BY CheckinID DESC LIMIT 1")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    checkin_id = row[0]
for checkin in data:
    if checkin.index() > checkin_id:
        ~do stuff~
```

Basically, I want to avoid duplicates based on what I already have in my database.

checkin.index() would be the following:

```
1. {u'abc': u'123', u'def': u'456'}
2. {u'abc': u'789', u'def': u'012'}
```

Comment: Just semantics, but a cursor is a single row, so your for-loop makes more sense to read as `for col in cursor.fetchall():`

Comment: I suppose that is true. ;-)

Comment: What's in the json file? Is it a `dict` indexed by `checkin_id`?

Comment: it doesn't have `checkin_id` in it. I am just trying to get the number that it is in the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
>>> my_dict = {'age': 18, 'name': 'jhon', 'sex': 'm'}
>>> for index,item in enumerate(my_dict.items()):
        print index, dict([item])
0 {'age': 18}
1 {'name': 'jhon'}
2 {'sex': 'm'}
```

---

Edit:

```
>>> data = [{u'abc': u'123', u'def': u'456'}, {u'abc': u'789', u'def': u'012'}]
>>> for item_with_index in enumerate(data):
        print item_with_index
(0, {u'abc': u'123', u'def': u'456'})
(1, {u'abc': u'789', u'def': u'012'})
```

Comment: Edited, you can still use `enumerate`.

Comment: but is there any way to single out the index? As in the above? `if index > checkin_id:`

Comment: `for index, item in enumerate(data): if index > checkin_id:` ?